# Implementing a clock face in UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, geometry

I'm trying to implement a clock face in UIView - without much luck.  The problem is that the hands on the clock face end up in totally the wrong position (i.e. pointing to the wrong time).  I'm pretty sure that the logic of my code is correct - but clearly there's something significantly wrong.

My test app is an iOS Single View Application.  ViewController.h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Clock : UIView {
    UIColor* strokeColour;
    UIColor* fillColour;
    float strokeWidth;
    NSDate* clockTime;
    CGPoint clockCentre;
    float clockRadius;
}
- (id)initWithCentre:(CGPoint)centre
              radius:(float)radius
         borderWidth:(float)width
          facecolour:(UIColor*)fill
          handcolour:(UIColor*)handFill
                time:(NSDate*)time;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

and ViewController.m looks like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation Clock

- (id)initWithCentre:(CGPoint)centre
              radius:(float)radius
         borderWidth:(float)width
          facecolour:(UIColor*)fill
          handcolour:(UIColor*)handFill
                time:(NSDate*)time {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(centre.x-radius,
                              centre.y-radius,
                              radius*2,
                              radius*2);

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    // Initialization code
    strokeColour = fill;
    fillColour = handFill;
    strokeWidth = width;
    clockRadius = radius;
    clockTime = time;
    clockCentre.x = frame.size.width/2;
    clockCentre.y = frame.size.height/2;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    double red, green, blue, alpha;

    CGRect circleRect;
    circleRect.origin.x = rect.origin.x+strokeWidth;
    circleRect.origin.y = rect.origin.y+strokeWidth;
    circleRect.size.width = rect.size.width - (strokeWidth*2);
    circleRect.size.height = rect.size.height - (strokeWidth*2);
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, strokeWidth);

    [fillColour getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, red, green, blue, alpha);

    [strokeColour getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, red, green, blue, alpha);

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circleRect);

    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, circleRect);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, strokeWidth);

    [strokeColour getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, red, green, blue, alpha);

    float  hourAngle, minuteAngle, secondAngle, angle;
    double endX, endY;

    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSUInteger units = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:units fromDate:clockTime];
    hourAngle = (components.hour /12.0) * M_PI * 2.0;
    minuteAngle = (components.minute / 60.0) * M_PI * 2.0;
    secondAngle = (components.second / 60.0) * M_PI * 2.0;

    //minute hand
    angle = minuteAngle;
    endX = cos(angle) * (clockRadius*0.85) + clockCentre.x;
    endY = sin(angle) * (clockRadius*0.85) + clockCentre.y;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef,clockCentre.x,clockCentre.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef,endX,endY);
    CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);

    //hour hand
    angle = hourAngle;
    endX = cos(angle) * (clockRadius*0.65) + clockCentre.x;
    endY = sin(angle) * (clockRadius*0.65) + clockCentre.y;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, strokeWidth*1.5);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(contextRef,clockCentre.x,clockCentre.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(contextRef,endX,endY);
    CGContextStrokePath(contextRef);
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (UIView*)drawClockFaceWithCentre:(CGPoint)centre
                            radius:(float)radius
                              time:(NSDate*)time
                            colour:(UIColor*)colour
                  backgroundColour:(UIColor*)bgcolour {

    UIView* clock = [[Clock alloc]initWithCentre:centre
                                          radius:radius
                                     borderWidth:6.0
                                      facecolour:bgcolour
                                      handcolour:colour
                                            time:time];

    clock.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return clock;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CGPoint centre;
    centre.x=200;
    centre.y=200;

    [self.view addSubview:[self drawClockFaceWithCentre:centre
                                                 radius:100
                                                   time:[NSDate date]
                                                 colour:[UIColor blackColor]
                                       backgroundColour:[UIColor whiteColor]]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I'm sure it's something very simple that I've done wrong - a mistake in my maths.  Can anyone see the bug (and any other suggestions for improvements that could be made would be welcome, bearing in mind (of course) that this is just a simple test harness).

Comment: Consider using CAShapeLayer for clock hands (one for each) and storing them as variables. Then just transform rotate them

Comment: That won't fix the problem though, will it?  Because I still need to rotate them - and it's my rotation that's the problem.  The angles are wrong.

Comment: No, but it would make for more readable code, easier to maintain and easier calculations (instead of trigonometry where it's easy to make a mistake you just need to get correct percent of 2pi).

Comment: "you just need to get correct percent of 2pi".  An interesting theory.  I tried it - but it doesn't work entirely.  Would it be possible for you to make the corrections to the code that you believe are necessary and reliable (and earn yourself a correct answer into the bargain?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, consider dropping doing everything in drawRect and use layers. Also, instead of calculating trigonometry to draw correct path, consider just drawing hands at 12:00 and transform rotate them with correct angle. You could do it like this in init...

```
CAShapeLayer *faceLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
faceLayer.frame = self.bounds;
faceLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
faceLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
faceLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:faceLayer.bounds].CGPath;
faceLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
[self.layer addSublayer:faceLayer];

CGPoint middle = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));

NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSUInteger units = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:units fromDate:time];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:middle];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(middle.x, middle.y-radius*0.5)];

CGFloat hourAreaAngle = (2*M_PI)/12.0;
CAShapeLayer *hourLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
hourLayer.frame = self.bounds;
hourLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
hourLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
hourLayer.path = path.CGPath;
[self.layer addSublayer:hourLayer];
hourLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((components.hour/12.0*(M_PI*2.0))+(hourAreaAngle*(components.minute/60.0)), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

[path removeAllPoints];
[path moveToPoint:middle];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(middle.x, middle.y-radius*0.8)];

CAShapeLayer *minuteLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
minuteLayer.frame = self.bounds;
minuteLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
minuteLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
minuteLayer.path = path.CGPath;
[self.layer addSublayer:minuteLayer];
minuteLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(components.minute/60.0*(M_PI*2.0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

[path removeAllPoints];
[path moveToPoint:middle];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(middle.x, middle.y-radius)];

CAShapeLayer *secondsLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
secondsLayer.frame = self.bounds;
secondsLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
secondsLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
secondsLayer.path = path.CGPath;
[self.layer addSublayer:secondsLayer];
secondsLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(components.second/60.0*(M_PI*2.0), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Note I put my colours and line widths because I'm lazy and didn't want to check your code :P.

If you want to update hands later, just store hands layers as variables and transform rotate them again (just remember to first transform to identity!).